# Filtering JavaScript objects using values from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have array of objects.

```
var products = [{
       names: ["hammer", "nail", "rubber duck"],
       colors: ["yellow", "red", "pink"]
    },
    {
       names: ["saw", "tractor", "bowling ball"],
       colors: ["gray", "purple", "green"]
    }]
```

Then I have object with arrays of filter values:

```
var filters = {names: ["saw", "bowling ball"], colors:["purple"]}
```

I need to filter the objects so that if I've got no filters I get all objects back. If I've got any filter values in "names" I get objects back with matching names. If I've got any filter values in both "names" and "colors" I get objects back with matching values on both.

For example:

```
var filters = {names: ["saw", "bowling ball"], colors:["purple"]}
```

would return

```
[{
names: ["saw", "tractor" "bowling ball"],
colors: ["gray", "purple", "green"]
}]
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` to iterate through your `products` array and inside it you can check for existence of `name` and `color` using `array#some` and `array#includes`.

```js
var products = [{ names: ["hammer", "nail", "rubber duck"], colors: ["yellow", "red", "pink"] }, { names: ["saw", "tractor", "bowling ball"],colors: ["gray", "purple", "green"] }],
    filters = {names: ["saw", "bowling ball"], colors:["purple"]};
var result = products.filter(({names, colors}) => {
  return filters.names.some(name => names.includes(name)) && filters.colors.some(color => colors.includes(color));
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested approach by filtering the given array with all items with the object for the wanted items and get the keys of it, take the arrays and look if the value is in the item's list with the same key.

```js
var products = [{ names: ["hammer", "nail", "rubber duck"], colors: ["yellow", "red", "pink"] }, { names: ["saw", "tractor", "bowling ball"], colors: ["gray", "purple", "green"] }],
    filters = { names: ["saw", "bowling ball"], colors: ["purple"] },
    result = products.filter(function (p) {
        return Object.keys(filters).every(function (k) {
            return filters[k].some(function (v) {
                return p[k].indexOf(v) !== -1;
            });
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const filterProducts = (filter, products) => {
        let len=products.length,i=0,
            filteredProducts = [];

        for(;i<len;i++) {
            let product = products[i];
            if(filters.names) {
                let names = getMatch(filters.names, product.names);
                if(names) {
                    if(!filteredProducts[i]) filteredProducts[i] = {};
                    filteredProducts[i].names = names;
                };
            }
            if(filters.colors) {
                let colors = getMatch(filters.colors, product.colors);
                if(colors) {
                    if(!filteredProducts[i]) filteredProducts[i] = {};
                    filteredProducts[i].colors = colors;
                };
            }
        }

        if(filteredProducts.length) return filteredProducts;
        return products;
    }

    const getMatch = (filter, values) => {
        let filterLength = filter.length;
        for(let i=0;i<filterLength;i++) {
            if(values.indexOf(filter[i]) !== -1) return values;
        }
    }

    let filtered = filterProducts(filters, products);
    console.log(filtered);
```